# How to delete record from sql

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Why this code are not working?

```
def deleted(self):
    id = self.res[i][6]    # it's int
    con = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("""DELETE from Table1 WHERE id = ?""", (id, ))
    cur.close()
    con.close()
```

Comment: looks pretty good except you forgot `con.commit()` to persist the change to the db file; after running the query and before closing the connection.

Answer (score 2):

After executing a query you need to commit it:
`con.commit()`